# Asp.net string creation gives operator "&" error VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a SQL string in Asp.net web page, with vb code behind.

It was working fine before but for unknown reason I start now getting the following error:

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Operator '&' is not defined for string "UPDATE `db`.`usersdata` SET `SH" and type 'TextBox'.

UPDATE: SH is a string ('SAVE' or 'HIDE')

UPDATE: I am using MySQL database on the background.

```
Protected Sub savehide_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

            Dim SQLstring As String = ""
            Dim SH As String
            SH = saveorhide.SelectedItem.Value
            ' the following line is where the error occurs
            SQLstring = "UPDATE `db`.`usersdata` SET `SH`='" & SH & "' WHERE `PIC` = '" & Session("UserId") & "'"
            Session("SH") = SH
            SQLNonQuery_mysql(SQLstring)
            CLEARALL()
            displaydata()    
    End Sub
```

I have spent hours but I cannot find the reason for this, specially when before it was working fine. 
This code runs when a dropdownlist field is changed.
The thing it also started to happen to other dropdownlist and SQL string creation code...So it is failing in various VB places now (as I said before it wasn't)
I am wondering if there is a bug or some weird reason why this error is coming out now (and not before) and what would be the solution.

Comment: Use sql-parameters, always, without exception.

Comment: Use sql parameters, don't concatenate! I see you are using `, the db might not threat it properly, have you tried removing them? Also, what is the value inside the SH variable?

Comment: I appreciate your comments. The error was due to wrong variable setting, which was fixed, however I will take note for of the sql parameters issues too, as I was not aware they were so important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, either `SH` is a TextBox or `Session("UserId")` is a TextBox.

Since you already showed the declaration of `SH`, the only suspect remaining is the `Session("UserId")`.

Can you show how you are setting the `Session("UserId")` value?

My best guess is that you are doing this:

```
Session("UserId") = TextBox1
```

you should change it to:

```
Session("UserId") = TextBox1.Text
```

(replace `TextBox1` with name of your TextBox)

Comment: YES!!! that was the problem ! I was using  Session("UserId") = TextBox1 instead of Session("UserId") = TextBox1.Text to set the session variable. I can't thank you enough ! That solved all the other problems as well!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped :)